# RemoteViews + TextView + setGravity

Tags: android, textview

I have app widget with TextView in it.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widgetText"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/defaultWidgetText"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

I'm trying to change text alignment by calling

```
views.setInt(R.id.widgetText, "setGravity", Gravity.CENTER);
```

from RemoteView. But it makes "Problem loading widget"
Other setInt(...) works fine.

I don't want create another TextViews or Layouts. Is there any other way to change Gravity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... Here is my solution.
Widget layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/top_left_text"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/top_text"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/top_right_text"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:gravity="top|right"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/left_text"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/center_text"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/right_text"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_left_text"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:gravity="bottom|left"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_text"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_right_text"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

And onUpdate(...) method:

```
widgetViews = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

widgetViews.put(GRAVITY_TOP_LEFT, R.id.top_left_text);
widgetViews.put(GRAVITY_TOP, R.id.top_text);
widgetViews.put(GRAVITY_TOP_RIGHT, R.id.top_right_text);

widgetViews.put(GRAVITY_LEFT, R.id.left_text);
widgetViews.put(GRAVITY_CENTER, R.id.center_text);
widgetViews.put(GRAVITY_RIGHT, R.id.right_text);

widgetViews.put(GRAVITY_BOTTOM_LEFT, R.id.bottom_left_text);
widgetViews.put(GRAVITY_BOTTOM, R.id.bottom_text);
widgetViews.put(GRAVITY_BOTTOM_RIGHT, R.id.bottom_right_text);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, MinimalisticNotesWidgetActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
for(int id : widgetViews.values())
{
    views.setViewVisibility(id, View.INVISIBLE);
}

int id = widgetViews.get(textGravity);

views.setOnClickPendingIntent(id, pendingIntent);
views.setTextViewText(id, widgetText);
views.setFloat(id, "setTextSize", fontSize);
views.setInt(id, "setTextColor", textColor);
views.setViewVisibility(id, View.VISIBLE);
```

P.S. I know, this is a bad coding style, but other variants in Internet looks the same = (

Answer (score 1):

My solution was:

```
// Text Align
int gravity = widget_pf.getInt(Constants.Prefs.WIDGET_TEXT_ALIGN, 2);
if (gravity == 0)
    remoteViews.setInt(R.id.BalancesLinLayout, "setGravity", Gravity.LEFT);
else if (gravity == 1)
    remoteViews.setInt(R.id.BalancesLinLayout, "setGravity", Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
else
    remoteViews.setInt(R.id.BalancesLinLayout, "setGravity", Gravity.RIGHT);
```

And in widget_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/BalancesLinLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SampleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="9sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So far, this was very simple.